# Meaning of 日の跡のささくれ

Tags: meaning, words

I am checking the lyrics for a track of music in which the words 日の跡のささくれ are repeated in two different lines, I know the meaning of words, but the meaning of the sentence is still vague for me.

> 迷った日の跡のささくれ
>
> ころんだ日の跡のささくれ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the pieces of your phrase.

- 日【ひ】 is just "day", pretty straightforward there.
- 跡【あと】 is the "afters" of something, "leftovers" or "marks" or "scars", the impact or effect made by something.
  → so 日【ひ】の跡【あと】 parses out to "the aftereffects or marks left by the day".
- ささくれ is the noun or stem form of the verb ささくれる ("to split finely from the ends").  ささくれ could refer to something that's splitting in this way, and is a synonym for 逆【さか】剥【む】け ("hangnail").
  Links to Weblio's [Japanese page](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C) and [English page](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C) for ささくれ.

Given the context in your two example lines, it sounds like the singer is describing small and slightly painful wounds left over as aftereffects of certain days, presumably using the term "hangnail" as a poetic allusion to a stinging emotional hurt.